# Trying to set values in a struct tm

Tags: c, function, time

I am trying to create a function that gets the current date, takes an individuals birthday, and calculates their age.  I got the current date.  Now I am trying to take the person's birthday(passed to the function through individual) and store the person's birthday values in a struct `tm` variable named str_bday.  The program compiles, but when I run it, i get this:

```
       Your last name is Smith
       Sat Feb  8 16:04:05 2014
       Your birthday is:  3/1/1940
       Wed Dec 31 18:59:59 1969
       v245-2%
```

I don't understand why it prints that their birthday is 1969 when I print out the str_bday struct `tm` variable.   Can somebody please help me.  Below is my code for this function:

```
       char* calcage(char *individual, char *age)
         {

           time_t current_time;
           char *c_time_string;

           current_time = time(NULL);


           c_time_string = ctime(&current_time);

           printf(c_time_string);



           char *birthday = (char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
           birthday = strrchr(individual, ',');
           birthday++;

           printf("Your birthday is:  %s\n", birthday);


           char *bmonth, *bday, *byear;
           int numbmonth, numbday,  numbyear;


           bmonth = strtok(birthday, "/");
           bday = strtok(NULL, "/");
           byear = strtok(NULL, "/");

           numbmonth = atoi(bmonth);
           numbday = atoi(bday);
           numbyear = atoi(byear);


           struct tm str_bday;
           time_t time_bday;

           str_bday.tm_year = 2012;

           time_bday = mktime(&str_bday);
           printf(ctime(&time_bday));



         }
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to read the fine manual: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3.html (especially the comments on the declaration of `struct tm`).

Comment: `char *birthday = (char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));` There is no need for malloc If you just point to the address.

Answer (score 1):

`tm_year` will set the year on the basis of the `1900`. (E.g `str_bday.tm_year = numbyear -1900;`)

also You should be checked as follows the return value of `mktime`.

```
if(time_bday == (time_t)-1)
    printf("error");
```

It returns an error if a year earlier because it is based on the 1970 on many systems.

Must be processed as of the date yourself if such.

---

Test code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(){
    struct tm str_bday = {0};
    time_t time_bday;

    str_bday.tm_year = 2012 - 1900;
    str_bday.tm_mon = 3 - 1;
    str_bday.tm_mday = 1;
    time_bday = mktime(&str_bday);
    if(time_bday == (time_t)-1)
        printf("error\n");
    else
        printf("%s\n", ctime(&time_bday));//Thu Mar 01 00:00:00 2012
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: even when I change it to:  str_bday.tm_year = 2012 - 1900;
it still gives me 1969

Comment: I was facing this error just now even when I set the values as mentioned in this answer. It seems that I did not initialize `struct tm` to 0 in the first place. Doing `struct tm str_bday = {0};` basically solved it for me.